# Running a PHP Server Status Script

Tags: uptime

I have a PHP script which checks whether a site is down using CURL. I want to know how to run it.
My problem.
I have 500 sites in my list. I was thinking of setting up a Cron job which will run in a regular interval. I have a shared hosting server by Hostgator. Will that Cron job consume too much resources? How can I calculate that and the time interval to set?

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome. :)

Thank you.

Comment: Server resource management is the task of the host. Don't worry about it. They will prioritize and deprioritize as they see fit.

Comment: Is setting up a cron job the only option for me to achieve this task?

Comment: Its probably your best option yeah

Comment: I will go ahead with that. Thank you for your suggestion Leemo. :)